# Dispatch and listen for event in child Livewire component not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have created a separate Livewire modal component. I want to reuse that component but fill it dynamically for different pages.

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class SlideOver extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.slide-over');
    }
}

View:
@props(['disabled' => false])

<div>
    <div x-on:show-post-modal.window="alert('test')"></div>
</div>
```

The html is not yet a modal for testing purposes. To trigger this modal I load the Livewire component first, at a later stage I want to use the slots to make it dynamic. For now I want to open the modal via a button, so I thought that that should work via the dispatch method. See code below.

```
<button wire:click="$dispatch('show-post-modal', { id: 1 })">
            EditPost
        </button>

        <livewire:slide-over>
            <x-slot name="cols">3</x-slot>
            <x-slot name="rows">10</x-slot>
        </livewire:slide-over>
```

But nothing is triggered, I also have tried to use listeners in the slideOver component, but that is also not working. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In the SlideOver component, you should explicitly mention that you're listening to an event. You can do this by defining a $listeners property on your component. This property should map the event name to the method that should be called when the event is fired.

```
namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class SlideOver extends Component
{
    protected $listeners = ['showPostModal' => 'handleShowPostModal'];

    public function handleShowPostModal($data)
    {
        // For now, just show an alert
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('alert', 'Modal should be shown');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.slide-over');
    }
}
```

You can continue using the $dispatch method, but you should make sure the event name matches the listener.

```
<button wire:click="$emit('showPostModal', { id: 1 })">
    EditPost
</button>

<livewire:slide-over>
    <x-slot name="cols">3</x-slot>
    <x-slot name="rows">10</x-slot>
</livewire:slide-over>
```

For Javascript, you should also listen for the browser event dispatched from the Livewire component:

```
<div wire:ignore x-data="{}" x-on:alert.window="alert('test')">
</div>
```